# How to get property value from Me.ActiveControl

Tags: vb.net

I have subclased form with _Keydown handler which should behave differently in different situations. For that I have code in subclass like this:

```
If Me.ActiveControl.GetType Is GetType(TextBox) Then

End if
```

Inside IF I have to check if textbox is multiline or not so I try that:

```
If Me.ActiveControl.GetType Is GetType(TextBox) Then
   If Me.ActiveControl.Multiline = True Then ...
```

but that don't go (program don't see properties of my textbox).

How to get properties like "Multiline" in such situation (from Me.ActiveControl)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well you still need to cast it to the actual control type...

ie:

```
If Me.ActiveControl.GetType Is GetType(TextBox) Then
   If CType(Me.ActiveControl, TextBox).Multiline = True Then ...
```

Answer (score 1):

That's how I would do it:

```
If Me.ActiveControl Is TextBox Then
  If DirectCast(Me.ActiveControl, TextBox).MultiLine Then
     'your code here
  End If
End If
```

Comment: @user973238 no worries. IMHO that's the cleanest way to achieve this.